# Condition check in XSLT to select particular elements in XML

Tags: xslt

I am transforming XML data with some conditions but for one of the check, it's not working.
Below is my input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderStatusUpdate fileType="Order Status Update" fileStartTime="2020-11-11 22:36:08 " fileEndTime=" 2020-11-11 23:36:25">
  <MessageHeader>
    <Standard>eBay_Enterprise</Standard>
    <HeaderVersion>EWS_eb2c_1.1</HeaderVersion>
    <VersionReleaseNumber>EWS_eb2c_1.1</VersionReleaseNumber>
    <SourceData>
      <SourceId>OMS</SourceId>
      <SourceType>OrderManagementSystem</SourceType>
    </SourceData>
    <DestinationData>
      <DestinationId>EE_OrderRTStatusXML</DestinationId>
      <DestinationType>MAILBOX</DestinationType>
    </DestinationData>
    <EventType>OrderStatus</EventType>
    <MessageData>
      <MessageId>20201111233723</MessageId>
      <CorrelationId>0</CorrelationId>
    </MessageData>
    <CreateDateAndTime>2020-11-11 23:37:23</CreateDateAndTime>
  </MessageHeader>
  <OrderStatusEvents>
    <OrderStatusEvent>
      <StoreCode>R21_US</StoreCode>
      <OrderId>101155883040</OrderId>
      <ExternalOrderId/>
      <WebOrderId>00201W008786173</WebOrderId>
      <OrderSource type="OrderClassifier">STORE-ORDER</OrderSource>
      <OrderLineId>1</OrderLineId>
      <OriginalOrderId/>
      <OriginalWebOrderId/>
      <OriginalOrderLineId/>
      <ItemId>88-0027615863</ItemId>
      <OrderStatusDetails>
        <OrderStatusDetail>
          <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2020-11-11 23:06:29</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
          <StatusName>Fulfilled and Invoiced</StatusName>
          <ReturnReason/>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <CancelReason/>
          <CancelReasonText/>
        </OrderStatusDetail>
      </OrderStatusDetails>
      <OrderShipmentDetails>
        <OrderShipmentDetail>
          <ShippingCarrier>FEDX</ShippingCarrier>
          <ShippingServiceLevel>RUEGND</ShippingServiceLevel>
          <ShippingTrackingNumber>124518478574</ShippingTrackingNumber>
          <ShippingTimestamp>2020-11-11 22:48:00</ShippingTimestamp>
        </OrderShipmentDetail>
      </OrderShipmentDetails>
    </OrderStatusEvent>
    <OrderStatusEvent>
      <StoreCode>R21_US</StoreCode>
      <OrderId>101155883040</OrderId>
      <ExternalOrderId/>
      <WebOrderId>00201W008786173</WebOrderId>
      <OrderSource type="OrderClassifier">STORE-ORDER</OrderSource>
      <OrderLineId>2</OrderLineId>
      <OriginalOrderId/>
      <OriginalWebOrderId/>
      <OriginalOrderLineId/>
      <ItemId>88-0027501642</ItemId>
      <OrderStatusDetails>
        <OrderStatusDetail>
          <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2020-11-11 23:06:29</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
          <StatusName>Fulfilled and Invoiced</StatusName>
          <ReturnReason/>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <CancelReason/>
          <CancelReasonText/>
        </OrderStatusDetail>
      </OrderStatusDetails>
      <OrderShipmentDetails>
        <OrderShipmentDetail>
          <ShippingCarrier>FEDX</ShippingCarrier>
          <ShippingServiceLevel>RUEGND</ShippingServiceLevel>
          <ShippingTrackingNumber>124518478574</ShippingTrackingNumber>
          <ShippingTimestamp>2020-11-11 22:48:00</ShippingTimestamp>
        </OrderShipmentDetail>
      </OrderShipmentDetails>
    </OrderStatusEvent>
    <OrderStatusEvent>
      <StoreCode>R21_US</StoreCode>
      <OrderId>101156041120</OrderId>
      <ExternalOrderId/>
      <WebOrderId>00201W008787110</WebOrderId>
      <OrderSource type=""/>
      <OrderLineId>1</OrderLineId>
      <OriginalOrderId/>
      <OriginalWebOrderId/>
      <OriginalOrderLineId/>
      <ItemId>88-0027627207</ItemId>
      <OrderStatusDetails>
        <OrderStatusDetail>
          <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2020-11-11 23:06:10</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
          <StatusName>Fulfilled and Invoiced</StatusName>
          <ReturnReason/>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <CancelReason/>
          <CancelReasonText/>
        </OrderStatusDetail>
      </OrderStatusDetails>
      <OrderShipmentDetails>
        <OrderShipmentDetail>
          <ShippingCarrier>UPS</ShippingCarrier>
          <ShippingServiceLevel>PBX04</ShippingServiceLevel>
          <ShippingTrackingNumber>1ZEW3573YW09535217</ShippingTrackingNumber>
          <ShippingTimestamp>2020-11-11 22:54:00</ShippingTimestamp>
        </OrderShipmentDetail>
      </OrderShipmentDetails>
    </OrderStatusEvent>
    <OrderStatusEvent>
      <StoreCode>R21_US</StoreCode>
      <OrderId>101156041120</OrderId>
      <ExternalOrderId/>
      <WebOrderId>00201W008787110</WebOrderId>
      <OrderSource type=""/>
      <OrderLineId>2</OrderLineId>
      <OriginalOrderId/>
      <OriginalWebOrderId/>
      <OriginalOrderLineId/>
      <ItemId>88-0027627223</ItemId>
      <OrderStatusDetails>
        <OrderStatusDetail>
          <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2020-11-11 23:06:10</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
          <StatusName>Fulfilled and Invoiced</StatusName>
          <ReturnReason/>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <CancelReason/>
          <CancelReasonText/>
        </OrderStatusDetail>
      </OrderStatusDetails>
      <OrderShipmentDetails>
        <OrderShipmentDetail>
          <ShippingCarrier>UPS</ShippingCarrier>
          <ShippingServiceLevel>PBX04</ShippingServiceLevel>
          <ShippingTrackingNumber>1ZEW3573YW09535217</ShippingTrackingNumber>
          <ShippingTimestamp>2020-11-11 22:54:00</ShippingTimestamp>
        </OrderShipmentDetail>
      </OrderShipmentDetails>
    </OrderStatusEvent>
  </OrderStatusEvents>
</OrderStatusUpdate>
```

Expected output should be.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<OrderStatuses>
  <MESSAGES>
    <COMMANDSTATUS ID="SHIPPED" DESCRIPTION="Goods Shipped">
      <ORDER O_ID="W008786173" TRACKING_URL="https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=124518478574">
        <ORDER_LINE OL_ID="1" SKU="27615863" QUANTITY="1"/>
        <ORDER_LINE OL_ID="2" SKU="27501642" QUANTITY="1"/>
      </ORDER>
    </COMMANDSTATUS>
  </MESSAGES>
</OrderStatuses>
```

But I am getting below output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderStatuses>
   <MESSAGES>
      <COMMANDSTATUS ID="SHIPPED" DESCRIPTION="Goods Shipped">
         <ORDER O_ID="W008786173"
                TRACKING_URL="https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=124518478574">
            <ORDER_LINE OL_ID="1" SKU="27615863" QUANTITY="1"/>
            <ORDER_LINE OL_ID="2" SKU="27501642" QUANTITY="1"/>
         </ORDER>
      </COMMANDSTATUS>
   </MESSAGES>
   <MESSAGES>
      <COMMANDSTATUS ID="SHIPPED" DESCRIPTION="Goods Shipped">
         <ORDER O_ID="W008787110"/>
      </COMMANDSTATUS>
   </MESSAGES>
</OrderStatuses>
```

What exactly I need is if OrderSource tag has value of 'STORE-ORDER', then only it should add MESSAGES tag and data in OrderStatuses root tag otherwise it shouldn't add MESSAGES tag.
Below is my XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="orderSource" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <OrderStatuses>
            <xsl:for-each-group
                select="/OrderStatusUpdate/OrderStatusEvents/OrderStatusEvent"
                group-by="/OrderStatusUpdate/OrderStatusEvents/OrderStatusEvent/WebOrderId">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                        <MESSAGES>
                            <COMMANDSTATUS>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when
                                        test="upper-case(./OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName) = 'FULFILLED AND INVOICED' and ./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">SHIPPED</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="DESCRIPTION">Goods Shipped</xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when
                                        test="upper-case(./OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName) = 'RETURN RECEIVED' and ./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">RETURNED</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="DESCRIPTION">Goods Returned</xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when
                                        test="upper-case(./OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName) = 'CANCELLED' and ./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">CANCELLED</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="DESCRIPTION">Goods Cancelled</xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <ORDER>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when
                                            test="substring(current-grouping-key(), 0, 6) = '00201' and ./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="O_ID"><xsl:value-of
                                                select='substring(current-grouping-key(), 6)' /></xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="O_ID"><xsl:value-of
                                                select='current-grouping-key()' /></xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:for-each
                                        select="current-group()[WebOrderId = current-grouping-key()]">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when
                                                test="upper-case(./OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName) = 'FULFILLED AND INVOICED' and ./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="TRACKING_URL">https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=<xsl:value-of
                                                    select='./OrderShipmentDetails/OrderShipmentDetail/ShippingTrackingNumber' /></xsl:attribute>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:for-each
                                        select="current-group()[WebOrderId = current-grouping-key()]">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="./OrderSource = 'STORE-ORDER'">
                                                <ORDER_LINE>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="OL_ID"><xsl:value-of
                                                        select='OrderLineId' /></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:choose>
                                                        <xsl:when
                                                            test="substring(ItemId, 0, 6) = '88-00'">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="SKU"><xsl:value-of
                                                                select='substring(ItemId, 6)' /></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="SKU"><xsl:value-of
                                                                select='ItemId' /></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                                    </xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="QUANTITY"><xsl:value-of
                                                        select='./OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/Qty' /></xsl:attribute>
                                                </ORDER_LINE>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </ORDER>
                            </COMMANDSTATUS>
                        </MESSAGES>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </OrderStatuses>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let me know how can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum necessary to show the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="OrderStatusUpdate/OrderStatusEvents/OrderStatusEvent"
    group-by="OrderSource">
    <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
        process items...
    </xsl:if>            
</xsl:for-each-group>
```